# Java keyboard input parsing in a console app

Tags: java, keyboard, jline

I've just started messing around with [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) to parse character input in console mode. It seems to work well, but I'm wondering:

Is there a nonblocking way in JLine to find out if characters are available? (i.e. like [`kbhit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c(VS.80).aspx) in Windows.)

I suppose I could always wrap keyboard input in its own thread which then offers the keyboard characters in a thread-safe queue to the main thread, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

**EDIT**: This is character-by-character parsing. I am not going to use a GUI. The usual InputStream I/O in Java in console mode requires you to hit the Enter key first (e.g. it's buffered input only). Please don't tell me character-by-character input in console mode is impossible in Java; it isn't. JLine does it using a portable interface with a platform-dependent implementation.

**Edit update**: I was able to hack together a helper class to do the blocking I/O in a worker thread (using JLine for the per-character I/O, warning: you have to parse Ctrl-C yourself!) & then communicate via a synchronized queue with an isempty() routine. For what I'm doing right now that's fine, but I would really like to know a Good Way To Do This In The Future.

Comment: Could you post an snipped of the answer? Looks very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.

I think the "right" way to do this is a worker thread that pours all the blocking I/O into a non-blocking queue.  Hava a look at [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) from [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a console to get non-blocking input without native libraries.

You'll have to write a Swing app and write a [KeyListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)

Read this tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html