# how can I detect arrow keys in java console not in GUI?

Tags: java

I'm writing an application and I need to detect arrow keys inside it.
C++ has the getch() function.
We want to take the input and then add a check on ASCII values.

How can we detect input arrow keys?
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572001/detecting-and-acting-on-keyboard-direction-keys-in-java

Answer (score 4):

I have written a Java class [RawConsoleInput](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/RawConsoleInput) that uses [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to call operating system functions of Windows and Unix. It can be used to read the arrow keys, but the character codes are different on Windows and Unix.

Comment: How can I read arrow keys with it?

Comment: @CATboardBETA just read from the console with `RawConsoleInput.read()`, press an arrow key and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks. This's much easier that trying to inject javascript in and stuff.

Comment: Actually, I do have an issue. `com.sun.jna.LastErrorException` isn't present in `com.sun.jna:jna` in the maven repo. Is this necessary?

Comment: Actually, I am getting quite a lot of errors in Intellij. I'm using Java 10.

Comment: @CATboardBETA You have to add the JNA JAR library (currently jna-5.8.0.jar) to your project. Download from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: This almost works, but after building with maven and running the output jar, I get `NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/LastErrorException`. There is a similar ClassNotFoundException as well.

Comment: @CATboardBETA You have to include the JNA JAR file in the class path at runtime.

Comment: I thought Intellij handled that for you? I have it added as an external library.