# How to put a keylistener in this method

Tags: java

So, I have this method (with nothing in it yet)

```
class Transmitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

and I want to put a keylistener in it, to detect when the space key is pressed.
I've looked at tutorials online, and they are all to complicated for my needs; I just want a simple "Print something in the console" when the space key is pressed. Thanks!

Comment: Making a KeyListener is pretty simple, so if you think the tutorial is advanced, then you need to go back to the basics.

Comment: I don't think you can have key listeners in console apps. You'll probably have to learn swing first. [You can emulate the behaviour by getting the raw console input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545388/how-can-i-detect-arrow-keys-in-java-console-not-in-gui) but I doubt it's easier.

Comment: Key Listeners are usually added to the JFrames and such, or some object. I do not believe that it is possible to add KeyListener to console itself.

Comment: A idea behind people asking about what code you have so far.. is a minimal working code (with errors and exceptions). You have just made a   humor out of it :)

Answer (score 0):

As some others have commented, there is no concept of a key listener from a console application. If you just want to read input keys from the console, you can use `System.in.read()` within a loop: [What is the use of System.in.read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446689/what-is-the-use-of-system-in-read-in-java)

Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: ok thanks! I just made a Jframe with nothing in it and that fixed my problem :D