# Check if the user is typing in the console window

Tags: java

Is there a way to check if the user is typing in the console window in Java?

I want the program print whatever I type if I type something, otherwise print out "No input".

The tricky part is I want the program keep looping and printing out "No input", and then when I type "abc", it would immediately print out "abc".

I tried to use Scanner to do this as:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(1){
    if(s.hasNext()) System.out.println(s.next());
    else System.out.println("No input");
}
```

But when I ran it, if I did not type anything, the program just stuck there without printing "No input". Actually, "No input" was never printed.

Comment: Which OS/terminal are you using?

Comment: Something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545388/how-can-i-detect-arrow-keys-in-java-console-not-in-gui

Comment: while (1 ) ... how is 1 a condition? Against what are you comparing it?

Comment: if its java, your code wont compile, while(1) is invalid syntax

Comment: Yeap, while(1) works for C/C++ but in java you need to put while(true)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong, it should be while(true). But it does not matter, after changing, it's still not working!

Answer (score 1):

From a command line, I see no chance to receive the input before hitting the "enter button". (unlike "onKeyDown/Up")

But considering & accepting this restriction, a simple solution is to use [Reader.ready()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready--):

> (..returns) `True` if the next `read()` is guaranteed not to block for input, `false` otherwise.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Reader rdr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        final Scanner s = new Scanner(rdr);
        while (true) {
            if (rdr.ready()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            } else {
                // use Thread.sleep(millis); to reduce output frequency
                System.out.println("No input");
            }
        }
    }
}
```