# "raw input" mode for java? (Eclipse)

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, input

I read these two threads

- [how can I detect arrow keys in java console not in GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545388/how-can-i-detect-arrow-keys-in-java-console-not-in-gui)
- [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

and a few more on this subject that mention a raw input mode for the console, but it's never said *how*, really. I have no GUI, using Eclipse for Java on a Windows system.

Comment: Did you read the answers? The "raw" mode appears to be UNIX specific. The answers had other more general solutions, such as using alternative consoles.

Comment: That second post is a verbatim copy of the other

Comment: Note that one answer is a direct copy of the other, and I've flagged the moderators. In the mean time, look into using jcurses.

Comment: Unless you want to delve into OS calls with JNI or JNA, and unless you're a pretty sharp programmer, I don't recommend this.