# How to detect "Up" / "Down" key is pressed by reading console input in Java?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I can read console input by:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String in = br.readLine();
```

The goal is to show last console input by pressing key "Up". When pressed console shows `^[[A` symbols. The code below does not detect when key "Up" is pressed:

```
switch (in) {
  case "^[[A"://Key up.
   //Do something - print previous input.
   break;
   //...
}

System.out.println(in);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting and acting on keyboard direction keys in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572001/detecting-and-acting-on-keyboard-direction-keys-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline possible duplicate

Comment: The string `"^[[A"` with the encoding obviously does not represent the same byte sequence than the arrow-input bytes. Read the linked duplicates, the match won't work.