# Make the console wait for a user input to close

Tags: java, console-application

I have a console application that after performing its tasks, must give feedback to the user, such as "operation completed" or "operation failed" and the detailed error.

The thing is, if I just "let it run", the output message will be printed but the console will close shortly afterwards, leaving no time to read the message.

As far as I remember, in C++, every console application will end with a "press any key to exit" or something like that. In C# I can simulate this behavior with a

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

But how can I do it in Java? I'm using the Scanner class, but given that "input" is my instance of Scanner:

```
input.next()
System.exit(0);
```

"Any key" will work, except for return, which is quite a big deal here. Any pointers?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In Java this would be `System.in.read()`

Comment: This satisfies "Press enter to exit" but not "Press any key to exit", since it will not continue until the enter key is pressed.

Comment: I suppose "press enter to exit" is still better than "press any key EXCEPT enter to exit". Thanks, that will do for me.

Comment: @marcolopes I'm a bit late to the party, but since you're asking about an app, I'm guessing the problem is that you're having the user hit the enter key in the GUI or somewhere else within the app. They need to hit the enter key in the console, which will most likely only be visible if you are running it within an IDE. You'll need a different solution if you want to press enter within an app.

Comment: System.in.read() reads exactly one byte, but ENTER may produce 1 or more bytes on different platforms, remember CRLF on Windows. So it may be that subsequent calls of read directly return LF from CRLF of the first call and therefore the app doesn't wait at all for input.

Comment: adding `import java.io.IOException;` is also required.

Answer (score 28):

I'd like to add that usually you'll want the program to wait only if it's connected to a console. Otherwise (like if it's a part of a [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)) there is no point printing a message or waiting. For that you could use Java's `Console` like this:

```
import java.io.Console;
// ...
public static void waitForEnter(String message, Object... args) {
    Console c = System.console();
    if (c != null) {
        // printf-like arguments
        if (message != null)
            c.format(message, args);
        c.format("\nPress ENTER to proceed.\n");
        c.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem with Java console input is that it's buffered input, and requires an enter key to continue.

There are these two discussions:
[Detecting and acting on keyboard direction keys in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572001/84378) and [Java keyboard input parsing in a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/414237/84378)

The latter of which used [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) to get his problem solved.

I personally haven't used it.

Answer (score 12):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Press enter to continue.....");

    s.nextLine();   
}
```

This `nextline` is a pretty good option as it will help us run next line whenever the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 11):

You can just use `nextLine();` as pause

```
import java.util.Scanner
//
//
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

void Read()
{
     System.out.print("Press any key to continue . . . ");
     scan.nextLine();
}
```

However any button you press except `Enter` means you will have to press Enter after that but I found it better than `scan.next();`

Comment: You need to use `Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 5):

I used simple hack, asking windows to use cmd commands , and send it to null.

```
// Class for Different hacks for better CMD Display
import java.io.IOException;
public class CMDWindowEffets
{
    public static void getch() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pause > null").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've put in what x4u said. Eclipse wanted a try catch block around it so I let it generate it for me.

```
try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It can probably have all sorts of bells and whistles on it but I think for beginners that want a command line window not quitting this should be fine.

Also I don't know how common this is (this is my first time making jar files), but it wouldn't run by itself, only via a bat file.

```
java.exe -jar mylibrary.jar
```

The above is what the bat file had in the same folder. Seems to be an install issue.

Eclipse tutorial came from:
http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/index.html

Some of the answer also came from: [Oracle Thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2447443)

Answer (score 1):

**A simple trick:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

/* Add these codes at the end of your method ...*/

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Press Enter to quit...");
input.nextLine();
```