# How can I print what is read by intputstream immediately?

Tags: java, io, stream, enter

This is the code I have:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        int read = inputStream.read();
        System.out.println(read);
    }
}
```

When I run this code inputStream will wait for input from the standard input which is fine. When I type 'a' in keyboard, I expect 97 to be printed immediately in the console. However this code requires me to hit 'Enter' after I type 'a'.

If I simply hit 'Enter' integer 10 will be shown in the console.

How can I modify the code so that as soon as I hit 'a' in the keyboard I see the integer 97? What is so special about the Enter button in this case? Why do I need to hit Enter?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-an-user-input-to-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there's no way to do this with the console in Java. No matter whether you use a `java.util.Scanner` or a kind of `java.io.InputStream` (including `System.in` directly), the `Enter` key is always the trigger for input to be received.

Consider using a graphical user interface like [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) (definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java))), where you can fulfill your input requirements by hooking up a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) to a text box.

Comment: Can I do it with JLine? I am trying to find out but I can't.

Comment: I doubt it, but I don't know for sure. Try it out!