# What is the best way to keep a Java program running forever, or for a very long time?

Tags: java, unix

I have java app which supports multiple workflows. Workflow is chosen using arguments passed to it from command line. In one of the workflow app needs to run for infinite time. I am achieving the same using following code

```
switch (args[0]) { 
    case "-runForever":
     // Some Computation
     Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
     break;
    case "otherCase:
     //dosomething
     break;
}
```

Is it a good way of achieving the required functionality?

Comment: It will keep running for a long time, vut it won't actually be doing anything... Unless you made it multithreaded?

Comment: @JohannisK in //some computation block this thread will register some callback handler with other services get triggered as and when needed.

Comment: Maybe better: System.in.read() ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-a-user-input-to-close

Answer (score 5):

You could use an infinite loop:

```
while(true){}
```

However, that would eat up the CPU for no reason. Instead, you could just call the wait() method:

```
synchronized{
   wait();
}
```

Then to resume, you'd call notify() from another thread.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep).

You could also just start another non-daemon Thread.

Comment: I will for sure explore this approach. But is this better then what I am doing?

Comment: @vikrant I'm not sure either one is better or worse. Go with whichever makes the most sense to you, because that will be the easiest to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

If all you want is for it to never reach the end why not

```
while (1)
```

Comment: I thought this will consume CPU cycles for each iteration

Comment: It will. The other answer is a better solution.

Comment: Also, while(1) would not compile in Java.