# Java wait for Serial Input

Tags: java, input, serial-port, wait

I linked a caliper to my computer with a RS232C-USB cable and I managed to get the data and print them in console. The caliper sends data everytime I press a pedal.

The problem is I can only acquire data once at the beginning, I'm searching for a function that would freeze the program, waiting for an input from the caliper before printing. The only one I have in mind is read(), but it doesn't seem to make the program wait for input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-an-user-input-to-close

Comment: @user1933888 I already went through both before posting, I have no problem to print the data I get in my Console, the only problem I meet is that the input is from something else than the keyboard, so the answers on the second link you posted are no great help, but still Thank you for the time you have taken to answer me