# Starting and Stopping Threads via user input

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I have a producer and consumer program implemented in Java. I would like to know how I can make the user type in "start" to start a new set of producer and consumer threads and type in "stop" to stop all the threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BoundedBuffer bb = new BoundedBuffer(buffer size: 5, producers: 10, consumers: 1);
    bb.start();
```

Comment: You can just set a flag to stop producers and consumers.  Also `Thread.interrupt()` is commonly used to stop threads.

Comment: The requirement is that the user has to type in start and stop. I wanted to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Wrap the following in a while True loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032118/make-the-console-wait-for-a-user-input-to-close
Inside the loop perform the action depending on the input.